# Unmouting datastore using VI Java

Tags: java, vcenter

I am using VI Java to create, delete and clone a VM.

I am unable to unmount datastores using VI Java.

How do I retrieve all the existing datastores so that I can call destroy_task() on the datastore I want?

( I don't know if this is a good idea - if it's not correct please suggest the best approach)